# How to drag the Android layout vertically?

Tags: android

My layout is fixed or when I do a new test appears more matches é'll be off the margin of the layout. I have no cursor to slide down. Please help! I try to find a solution e I found nothing.

The program uses textView.

Comment: my layout is fixed, when I retested more matches and it will be displayed outside the margin of the layout. I have no cursor to slide down. Please help! I try to find a solution e I found nothing. it's urgent

The program uses textView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your TextView with a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).